# get fonts in css from firebase storage link?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use a font that I uploaded in the firebase storage, (I use angular ionic firestore)

orginal font name:'Pacifico.ttf'

firebase font download link:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/questions-21b31.appspot.com/o/fonts%2Fgp6tcr9jkw4qo9mx?alt=media&token=9b62f1d0-2b22-40d7-8a72-1300ca5e3503

my try in css dosen't work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/questions-21b31.appspot.com/o/fonts%2Fgp6tcr9jkw4qo9mx?alt=media&token=9b62f1d0-2b22-40d7-8a72-1300ca5e3503) format('ttf');
}  

.testF{    
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

any idea?

thanks